# Can I rename an email address in Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-email

I have a `.pl` domain with Google Apps for your domain - mostly for email management. Now one of the users in this domain want to change her email address to a new one (surname change).

What is the easiest way to do it? I haven't found any 'rename' email address option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is possible](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=08bf846f5b0eb89a&hl=en), but apparently only through the Provisioning API, witch is only available to Premier and Education Edition domains.

If you don't have one of those, you could simply create an [alias for that account](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327) and [set up a custom from address](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370), so new mail is sent from that alias.

Comment: An alias is probably the best bet, since you will still get mail addressed to the old address.

Comment: Agreed with @pkaeding about continuing to get the old email, too.